# Angular5 RXJS recursive http requests

Tags: rxjs, angular5, fork-join

I currently have this situation:

```
#Service My Service
private users = ['user1','user2'];

//Generate list of requests to join
private getHttpList(): any[] {
  let gets = new Array();
  for(let index in this.users)
      gets.push(this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.users[index]))
  return gets;
}
...
getList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return forkJoin(this.getHttpList())
}
```

And in my component, I do the subscribe

```
this.MyService.getList().subscribe(results => {
    for(let res in results) {
       //...Do something here
       //..I wanna do the get in of https://api.github.com/users/{user}/starred
    }
})
```

Suppose that I just know that the "starred url" after the result of getList(), how to I can "synchronous" this part, or what's the correct form to do this?

**I try do it hardcoded --Result id wrong, because the "res" is a "interable"

```
this.MyService.getList().subscribe(results => {
        let url = 'https://api.github.com/users/';
        for(let res in results) {//This don't do the things "synchronous"
           this.http.get(url + res.login +'/starred').catch(err => {
               throw new Error(err.message);
           }).subscribe(starred_res => {
               //So we set the starred_list
               res.starred_list = starred_res 
           })
        }
    })
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to get starred list for every user.

The simplest way is to get all starred lists and **match** them with users result.

```js
// Get users
this.MyService.getList().subscribe((results: any[]) => {

  const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/';

  // Create requests to get starred list for every user
  const starredRequests = results.map(
    res => this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + res.login + '/starred')
  );

  // Wait when all starred requests done and map them with results array
  Observable.forkJoin(starredRequests).subscribe(starred => {

    results.forEach((res, index) => {
      res.starred_list = starred[index];
    });

    console.log(results);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. So, always that I have a "nested requests", need do a "forkJoin" and ensure that this "index of the list"?

Another question is: How I can do a "async request" and reflect this for one element of list? Therefore, suppose that I wanna get the value of "likes" from a post in facebook, and this result not need be pre-loaded, it can answer in any moment, and with this result, I wanna puts this value in some specific item of my list.

Comment: The common use of "forkJoin" is to join multiple http requests. If you want to do "async request" for every item you can use "mergeMap" operator.